# Avoiding global state in a dynamically created menu

Tags: architecture, state, software-design, state-management

I'm trying to write a game for my own learning and I've come up against a design problem which is breaking my brain.  It's a fairly simple turn-based game where the player has their own state, an inventory, and a home all with state; ideally I'd like to add some stateful elements in the rest of the world.

I'm trying to present the player with what options they have available to them at any time.  I've tried creating each option in the game flow control but it became unmanageable, so I'm trying to use better design now.  My number one idea is to have an Action class, each instance of which has some kind of state test encoded into it.  That way I can define the possible actions in one big configuration file, and when it comes to presenting the user with options, I can just iterate over the Action.available tests and the ones that return true get presented.

```
#obligatory pseudopython
class Action:
    def __init__ (self, available_test, other_args):
        #available is a function passed in, or perhaps some SQL query
        self.available = available_test

....
for a in action_array:
    if a.available():
    #or maybe if test_handler(a.available)
        options.append(a.option)

gui.show_menu(options)
```

The problem with this seems to be that the Action objects (or maybe the handler) will need global access to all game state in order to see if they can be performed.  This immediately raised warning flags in my head, but I can't see a way round it.  Having one handler that has all the access doesn't sound so bad, but that raises the issue of how to specify the tests, unless I put all the data in a database and write the tests in SQL.  If I do that, though, I'm bypassing every data access method in the whole program, which also seems to go against good design.

What am I doing wrong in my thinking?  Is there a better way of doing it?  I'm not particularly wedded to this way of doing things, I haven't written much code in this version and I'm happy to start from scratch (having done so once already).  I'm poring over a borrowed copy of Code Complete to try to give me some idea but while it all sounds pretty solid, I'm still scratching my head over what to actually *do*.

Just to be clear: I'm designing the way state is stored simultaneously; I want the Action system and state storage to work together harmoniously.  To some extent, I want to design state management around robust but simple access by Actions.  I'm writing in Python, but with a purpose of learning good software design skills in general, so I'd slightly prefer non-language-specific answers.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that going global is not the way to go.  Also it would not be good to bloat the definition of a playing character by adding internally every possible action on every possible object.  However, I don't think using Action objects is the right way to organize either.  An action is not generally meaningful apart from the object(s) for which the action is applicable.  You can unlock a lock, but not a rock.

Plus, if you have a character moving around in different locations, you probably have a way that each location provides information about the objects that are present in that location.  For movable objects, the location can become "on the person" and you probably have a way to request an inventory for the character, which will provide a list of objects.

I would suggest that the cleanest way to organize actions would be to have each ActionableObject know what actions can be performed on it or with it, including knowing the requirements for each action.  For each object in the locality, or for any object in one's inventory, it should be possible for the character to obtain the actions that could be done on/with that object via a request to the object itself.

**function WhatActionsCouldIDo**

Inputs include

1. the character making the request (often the player character, but
   could eventually be a non-player character if you have NPCs running
   with an AI)
2. the present location, unless you always already maintain current location information within the object itself

The output is a list of possible actions that could be done to or with that object.

Internally the object would consider each of its possible defined actions and execute a function to check whether the requirements of that action are satisfied, given (as inputs) the character and the location.  Via the character argument, the function could investigate the attributes of the character (e.g. Is he strong enough and unburdened enough to lift me?  Does he have the missing piece that completes me in his inventory?  Am I in the right location for the action to be *possible* (which may be different from whether the attempted action would have any effect)?  etc.)

If requirements are satisfied, the checking function returns true and the action is added to the list of actions that will be returned as output.

Likewise the object would also provide a function to **execute** a chosen action.

**function DoAction**

Inputs include

1. the chosen action (from previously obtained list)
2. the character making the request (often the player character, but
   could eventually be a non-player character if you have NPCs running
   with an AI)
3. the present location, unless you always already maintain current location information within the object itself

Even though a requirements check was done to obtain the list of actions, the safest path is to check again that the requirements are still satisfied.  Provided they are, the object calls a function to execute the action.

Note that within this design, when an action is requested, the object will manipulate the state of the character and the environment, which might seem odd at first.  However, this is in response to the *choice* of the character to execute the action, thus producing the action's *effects* on the character or the environment.  The object mediates this progression by providing the necessary internal knowledge of all the requirements (including those that are not apparent) and the ability to cause all effects to happen as a result (including subtle effects that the character may not have known about or intended, e.g. triggers some trap or has non-advertised effects on the character).

This arrangement should allow keeping the character object itself very clean and lean, needing only to expose interfaces to allow desired changes to its state, e.g. to add something to its inventory, boost or weaken an attribute, etc.

This arrangement also allows much freedom for adding new objects that have possible actions and effects that you did not anticipate originally.  Often everything that would need to be added can be placed within the new object type itself, using the existing interfaces to the character and the locations of the environment.  To maximize this, I recommend that the list of actions be expressed in generic terms, e.g. using combinations of integers and/or text.  The character class should not be dependent on awareness of all possible objects or all possible actions.  It just interacts at a generic level that provides the user with enough information to choose.

(On the other hand, you might need to adapt a revised approach if you wanted to add NPCs that use AI and need to understand the different actions in order to work out strategy.  That path will tend to lead to a much more constrained universe of possibilities in contrast to the unbounded possibilities of the above design.)